# solving calculus problem by two methods and getting same solution but different sign, Why?

Tags: calculus, integration

for closed curve $x^2 + y^2 = 1$
integral $y\,dx$ over the closed curve can be found by two methods where the orientation of the curve is in anticlockwise direction.

1. one is by using cartesian coordinates and,

$$\oint y\,dx \quad \text{over the closed curve}\quad x^2 + y^2 = 1$$

$$= 2 \int_{-1}^1\sqrt{1-x^2}\,dx$$
where $x$ is from $-1$ to $1$

by solving this we get answer $\pi$.

2. other one by converting cartesian into polar coordinates
   $x= r\cos\theta$ and   $y=r\sin\theta$

here $r=1$,
so integral becomes

$$\int_o^{2\pi}\sin\theta(-\sin\theta)\,d\theta$$  where $\theta$ is from $0$ to $2\pi$.

by solving this I am getting answer $-\pi$.

Now I don't understand why this sign differ in both method

where I'm doing wrong?

[Here I solved the problem by two methods but getting alternate sign in both solutions.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zeVVQ.jpg)

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It is in your best interest that you type your posts (using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)) instead of posting links to pictures.

Comment: Please do not use pictures for critical portions of your post. Pictures may not be legible, cannot be searched and are not view-able to some, such as those who use screen readers.

Comment: $\int_{-1}^1\sqrt{1-x^2}dx$ integrates the upper semi-circle left-to-right; ie, *clockwise*. To convert this to *anticlockwise* (as the question describes), you can adjust this by either negating the integrand as $-\sqrt{1-x^2}$ (representing the *lower* semi-circle), or swapping the limits of integration as $\int_{1}^{-1}$ (hence, right-to-left); either option has the effect of changing the sign of the resulting value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For method 1, don't be so quick to use one integral for both the upper semicircle and the lower semicircle. Look at them individually first.

For the upper semicircle, $y = \sqrt{1 - x^2}$.
As you integrate counterclockwise on the semicircle, $x$ goes from $1$ to $-1$.
So the integral on this semicircle should be
$$
\int_1^{-1} \sqrt{1 - x^2}\, \mathrm dx, \tag1
$$

**not**
$$
\int_{-1}^1 \sqrt{1 - x^2} \,\mathrm dx. \tag2
$$
Integral $(2)$ goes the wrong way around the circle.

For the lower semicircle, $x$ actually does go from $-1$ to $1$ as you supposed in your integral, but $y = -\sqrt{1 - x^2}$. So the correct integral is
$$
\int_{-1}^1 -\sqrt{1 - x^2} \,\mathrm dx. \tag3
$$

It is simple to confirm that integral $(3)$ is equal to integral $(1)$ and is exactly the additive inverse of integral $(2)$ (that is, opposite sign).
So you can evaluate just one of the integrals and double it, but that integral has to be $(1)$ or $(3)$ and not $(2)$. That way you get the correct sign.

---

As another way to see why integral $(2)$ is "the wrong way",
consider how it is usually evaluated, namely, by trigonometric substitution.
With the substitution $x = \cos\theta$, $y = \sin\theta$
on the interval $[0,\pi]$ (which is valid for the upper semicircle),
we have
$$
\int_{-1}^1 \sqrt{1 - x^2} \,\mathrm dx =
\int_\pi^0 (\sin\theta)(-\sin\theta) \,\mathrm d\theta.
$$
Here, $\theta$ runs from $\pi$ to $0$, which is the clockwise direction on the upper semicircle. But we want to go in the counterclockwise direction.